# Elasticsearch in Arabic text different character shapes

Tags: elasticsearch, arabic

I have an Elasticsearch index contains arabic text field I need to be able to search for "أحمد" and get the result of "أحمد" ,"احمد" and "آحمد"

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with Arabic texts, it might make sense to index your data using an Arabic analyzer. Here is a quick example to get you started, but I would strongly suggest reading about and understanding how [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) work.

```
DELETE arabic_example
PUT arabic_example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
     "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "arabic"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT arabic_example/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"text":"احمد"}
{"index": {}}
{"text":"أحمد"}
{"index": {}}
{"text":"آحمد"}

POST arabic_example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "أحمد"
    }
  }
}
```